# MySQL Left Joins unexpected output

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a *questionnaire* styled website, where someone can create a *questionnaire* and then either answer it as the person who created it or invite people to answer it.

I am currently having tones of issues when attempting to use joins.

- When someone answers as an admin but they are not invited to their own *questionniare* I get the errors shown below.
- When someone doesn't answer as an admin but I attempt to run the query it I seem to get the same response.

**tl;dr: I am attempting to bring back two rows, with information. As a *questionniare* admin who isn't invited to a *questionnaire***

```
SELECT cat.catID, cat.catName, cat.catPerms, cat.projectNumber, 
        CASE
            WHEN cat.catID IS NOT NULL AND count(ANS.itemID) = 0 THEN "Awaiting Response"
            WHEN count(ANS.itemID) > 0 THEN "Responded"
        END AS "status"
    FROM categories AS cat
    INNER JOIN invited AS invtee ON cat.catID = invtee.catID
    INNER JOIN answers AS ANS ON cat.catID = ANS.catID
        WHERE invtee.invEmail = "stack@overflow.com"

UNION ALL

SELECT cat.catID, cat.catName, cat.catPerms, cat.projectNumber, 
        CASE
            WHEN count(ANS.itemID) = 0 THEN "Awaiting Response"
            WHEN count(ANS.itemID) > 0 THEN "Responded"
        END AS "status"
    FROM categories AS cat
    LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS ANS ON cat.catID = ANS.catID AND ANS.userEmail = "stack@overflow.com"
        WHERE cat.adminEmail = "stack@overflow.com";
```

Tables that are relevant to the query...

`categories`:

```
| catID | catName | adminName | adminEmail | catDate | catPerms | projectNumber |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+---------------+
| 1     | Stack   | Stack ... | stack@o... | ...     | 0        | ...           |
| 2     | Over    | Stack ... | stack@o... | ...     | 0        | ...           |
```

`invited` (meant to be empty):

```
| invID | catID | invName | invEmail |
+-------+-------+---------+----------+
|       |       |         |          |
```

`answers`:

```
| answerID | catID | itemID | choiceID | userName | userEmail | answerText | answerStatus |
+----------+-------+--------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 1        | 1     | 1      | 2        | Stack... | stack@... | ...        | 1            |
```

Output:

```
| catID | catName | catPerms | projectNumber | Status    |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+
| 1     | Over    | 0        | ...           | Responded |
| NULL  | NULL    | NULL     | NULL          | NULL      |
```

What would be the best way to solve this?

Edit:
Within this statement, it seems that the `left outer join` is being ignored.

```
SELECT cat.catID, cat.catName, cat.catPerms, cat.projectNumber, 
        CASE
            WHEN count(ANS.itemID) = 0 THEN "Awaiting Response"
            WHEN count(ANS.itemID) > 0 THEN "Responded"
        END AS "status"
    FROM categories AS cat
    LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS ANS ON cat.catID = ANS.catID AND ANS.userEmail = "stack@overflow.com"
        WHERE cat.adminEmail = "stack@overflow.com";
```

Comment: you mean, to avoid the line with NULL values?

Comment: @Regenschein, I don't even know at this point - I've just been slammed onto this website with this random query trying to return two rows, even if the admin isnt an invitee or hasnt answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT cat.catID, cat.catName, cat.catPerms, cat.projectNumber, 
        CASE
            WHEN cat.catID IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(ANS.itemID) = 0 THEN "Awaiting Response"
            WHEN  COUNT(ANS.itemID) > 0 THEN "Responded"
        END AS STATUS
    FROM categories AS cat
    INNER JOIN invited AS invtee ON cat.catID = invtee.catID
    INNER JOIN answers AS ANS ON cat.catID = ANS.catID
        WHERE invtee.invEmail = "stack@overflow.com"  AND cat.catID IS NOT NULL AND cat.catID >0

UNION ALL

SELECT cat.catID, cat.catName, cat.catPerms, cat.projectNumber, 
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(ANS.itemID) = 0 THEN "Awaiting Response"
            WHEN COUNT(ANS.itemID) > 0 THEN "Responded"
        END AS STATUS
    FROM categories AS cat
    LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS ANS ON cat.catID = ANS.catID AND ANS.userEmail = "stack@overflow.com"
        WHERE cat.adminEmail = "stack@overflow.com" AND cat.catID >0
)AS T HAVING T.status IS NOT NULL
```